# Getting outputs in desired format from ast

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

this is a question regarding getting the desired output from python ast. Let me begin by showing the code that I am parsing with the python ast module. It is as shown below.

```
a = (3>> 4) | (5>6) 
#checks = ([3,4,5] > [1,2,3]) & (['a',b,2.3] > ['a',c,3.2,3])
bro = "hehe"
b = OneHotEncoding('x,y')
b.fit()
b.transform()
b.fit_transform()


# Path has been given to you already to use in function.
path = "./data/ipl_dataset.csv" #path to the csv file

a = np.zeros((1, 2, 3))
b = np.ones((1, 3, 4))
c = np.sum(c)
#x1, x2 = (0, 1)
m1,m2 = [np.zeros(),1.2,[pd.read_csv(),2]]
# random.shuffle(m)

#y1, y2 = a, b

a = (1,(1,2))
z1, z2 = [2, 4]

# m1, m2 = np.zeros(2), np.ones(4)

# m11, m12 = (np.zeros(2), np.ones(4))

son = {"dd": '4', "mm":[1,2,3]}
```

Now I am using the below code from ast to obtain information from the code particularly using the nodevisitor.

```
class allnames(ast.NodeVisitor):
def __init__(self):
    self._name = []
    self._imports = []

@property
def name(self):
    return self._name
@property
def imports(self):
    return self._imports

def visit_Name(self,node):
    self._name.append(node.id)


def visit_Attribute(self, node):
    try:

        self._name.append(node.value.id+'.'+node.attr)

    except AttributeError:
        self.generic_visit(node)

def visit_Num(self,node):
    self._name.append(node.n)

def visit_Str(self,node):
    self._name.append(node.s)
```

Further a helper function which will return all the assigns which is as follows.

```
def get_all_assigns(tree):
func_calls = []
for node in ast.walk(tree):
    if isinstance(node, ast.Assign):
        callvisitor = allnames()
        callvisitor1 = allnames()
        callvisitor1.visit(node.targets[0])

        callvisitor.visit(node.value)
        func_calls.append([callvisitor.name,callvisitor1.name])

return func_calls
```

Using this solves my problem partially to obtain the all the assigns and target but not in the format required. For instance it does not capture the ast.BinOp. Let's take a look at the output obtained in this case.

```
[[[3, 4, 5, 6], ['a']],


[['hehe'], ['bro']],
 [['OneHotEncoding', 'x,y'], ['b']],
 [['./data/ipl_dataset.csv'], ['path']],
 [['np.zeros', 1, 2, 3], ['a']],
 [['np.ones', 1, 3, 4], ['b']],
 [['np.sum', 'c'], ['c']],
 [['np.zeros', 1.2, 'pd.read_csv', 2], ['m1', 'm2']],
 [[1, 1, 2], ['a']],
 [[2, 4], ['z1', 'z2']],
 [['dd', 'mm', '4', 1, 2, 3], ['son']],
 [['b'], ['a']]]
```

lets take a look at two things here firstly the dictionary named son at the 32'nd line in the code which is parsed to obtain the output. It has keys dd,mm where the values associated with the key dd is a str and kk is a list [1,2,3]. I would like to obtain the value as key with the corresponding value in this case [dd,'4'] and [mm,[1,2,3]] also would like to capture BinOp for instance the ones that are used in a = (3>> 4) | (5>6). How do I add visit_Dict and visit_BinOp to get these values?

Thanks in advance for the answer

Comment: You can just `def visit_BinOp(self, node)` the same way you defined `visit_Name`, and you'll get called with each `BinOp`, like `BinOp(left=Num(n=3), op=RShift(), right=Num(n=4)`. But I have no idea what you want to _do_ with that `BinOp`, so I'm not sure what you want explained here.

Comment: And the same goes for the dict—just add a `visit_Dict` method and do whatever you want there. For example, you'll get a `node` like `Dict(keys=[Str(s='dd'), Str(s='mm')], values=[Str(s='4'), List(elts=[Num(n=1), Num(n=2), Num(n=3)], ctx=Load())])`, so you can just `zip(node.keys, node.values)` and do… whatever it is you want with them, but again I can't tell what it is you want to do.